# selenium multithreading python

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, web-scraping

I wrote a selenium script to check the case statuses of uscis cases an I want to speed it up as I am trying to check more than 500 cases every time.

**How to use it with multithreading of concurrent futures library in python?**

```
import re
import json
from datetime import date
from unittest import case
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from multiprocessing import Pool
import concurrent.futures
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
# browser = webdriver.Chrome('PATH', options=options)
cases = []
def getStatus(CN):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('PATH', options=options)
    browser.get("https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/landing.do")
    serachField = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/fieldset/div[1]/div[4]/input')
    serachField.click()
    serachField.send_keys(CN)
    searchButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/fieldset/div[2]/div[2]/input')
    searchButton.click()
    try:
        outputFieldHeading = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/h1')
        outputField = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/p')
        dateMatch = re.search(r'\w+\s\d+,\s\d+', outputField.text)
        try:
            formMatch = re.search(r'([I][-]\d+,^)|([I][-]\d+\w)', outputField.text)
            formNumber = formMatch.group()
        except:
            formNumber = "Form Unknown"
        cases.append({'caseNumber': CN,'currentDate': today, 'Date': dateMatch.group(), 'FormNumber': formNumber, 'Status': outputFieldHeading.text, 'Description': outputField.text})
        print(f"{CN} : {outputFieldHeading.text} : {dateMatch.group()} : {formNumber}")
        return f"{CN} : {outputFieldHeading.text} : {dateMatch.group()} : {formNumber}"
    except NoSuchElementException:
        cases.append({'caseNumber': CN,'currentDate': today, 'Date': "Unknown", 'FormNumber': "Unknown Form", 'Status': "Not Found", 'Description': ""})
        print(f"{CN} : Not Found")
        return f"{CN} : Not Found"
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    casenumbers = ["EAC2134250100", "EAC2134250101", "EAC2134250102", "EAC2134250103", "EAC2134250104", "EAC2134250105", "EAC2134250106", "EAC2134250107", "EAC2134250108", "EAC2134250109", "EAC2134250110", "EAC2134250111", "EAC2134250112", "EAC2134250113", "EAC2134250114", "EAC2134250115", "EAC2134250116", "EAC2134250117", "EAC2134250118", "EAC2134250119", "EAC2134250120", "EAC2134250121", "EAC2134250122", "EAC2134250123", "EAC2134250124", "EAC2134250125", "EAC2134250126", "EAC2134250127", "EAC2134250128", "EAC2134250129", "EAC2134250130", "EAC2134250131", "EAC2134250132", "EAC2134250133", "EAC2134250134", "EAC2134250135", "EAC2134250136", "EAC2134250137", "EAC2134250138", "EAC2134250139", "EAC2134250140", "EAC2134250141", "EAC2134250142", "EAC2134250143", "EAC2134250144", "EAC2134250145", "EAC2134250146", "EAC2134250147", "EAC2134250148", "EAC2134250149", "EAC2134250150", "EAC2134250151", "EAC2134250152", "EAC2134250153", "EAC2134250154", "EAC2134250155", "EAC2134250156", "EAC2134250157", "EAC2134250158", "EAC2134250159", "EAC2134250160", "EAC2134250161", "EAC2134250162", "EAC2134250163", "EAC2134250164", "EAC2134250165", "EAC2134250166", "EAC2134250167", "EAC2134250168", "EAC2134250169", "EAC2134250170", "EAC2134250171", "EAC2134250172", "EAC2134250173", "EAC2134250174", "EAC2134250175", "EAC2134250176", "EAC2134250177", "EAC2134250178", "EAC2134250179", "EAC2134250180", "EAC2134250181", "EAC2134250182", "EAC2134250183", "EAC2134250184", "EAC2134250185", "EAC2134250186", "EAC2134250187", "EAC2134250188", "EAC2134250189", "EAC2134250190", "EAC2134250191", "EAC2134250192", "EAC2134250193", "EAC2134250194", "EAC2134250195", "EAC2134250196", "EAC2134250197", "EAC2134250198", "EAC2134250199", "EAC2134250200", "EAC2134250201", "EAC2134250202", "EAC2134250203", "EAC2134250204", "EAC2134250205", "EAC2134250206", "EAC2134250207", "EAC2134250208", "EAC2134250209", "EAC2134250210", "EAC2134250211", "EAC2134250212", "EAC2134250213", "EAC2134250214", "EAC2134250215", "EAC2134250216", "EAC2134250217", "EAC2134250218", "EAC2134250219", "EAC2134250220", "EAC2134250221", "EAC2134250222", "EAC2134250223", "EAC2134250224", "EAC2134250225", "EAC2134250226", "EAC2134250227", "EAC2134250228", "EAC2134250229", "EAC2134250230", "EAC2134250231", "EAC2134250232", "EAC2134250233", "EAC2134250234", "EAC2134250235", "EAC2134250236", "EAC2134250237", "EAC2134250238", "EAC2134250239", "EAC2134250240", "EAC2134250241", "EAC2134250242", "EAC2134250243", "EAC2134250244", "EAC2134250245", "EAC2134250246", "EAC2134250247", "EAC2134250248", "EAC2134250249", "EAC2134250250", "EAC2134250251", "EAC2134250252", "EAC2134250253", "EAC2134250254", "EAC2134250255", "EAC2134250256", "EAC2134250257", "EAC2134250258", "EAC2134250259", "EAC2134250260", "EAC2134250261", "EAC2134250262", "EAC2134250263", "EAC2134250264", "EAC2134250265", "EAC2134250266", "EAC2134250267", "EAC2134250268", "EAC2134250269", "EAC2134250270", "EAC2134250271", "EAC2134250272", "EAC2134250273", "EAC2134250274", "EAC2134250275", "EAC2134250276", "EAC2134250277", "EAC2134250278", "EAC2134250279", "EAC2134250280", "EAC2134250281", "EAC2134250282", "EAC2134250283", "EAC2134250284", "EAC2134250285", "EAC2134250286", "EAC2134250287", "EAC2134250288", "EAC2134250289", "EAC2134250290", "EAC2134250291", "EAC2134250292", "EAC2134250293", "EAC2134250294", "EAC2134250295", "EAC2134250296", "EAC2134250297", "EAC2134250298", "EAC2134250299", "EAC2134250300", "EAC2134250301", "EAC2134250302", "EAC2134250303", "EAC2134250304", "EAC2134250305", "EAC2134250306", "EAC2134250307", "EAC2134250308", "EAC2134250309", "EAC2134250310", "EAC2134250311", "EAC2134250312", "EAC2134250313", "EAC2134250314", "EAC2134250315", "EAC2134250316", "EAC2134250317", "EAC2134250318", "EAC2134250319", "EAC2134250320", "EAC2134250321", "EAC2134250322", "EAC2134250323", "EAC2134250324", "EAC2134250325", "EAC2134250326", "EAC2134250327", "EAC2134250328", "EAC2134250329", "EAC2134250330", "EAC2134250331", "EAC2134250332", "EAC2134250333", "EAC2134250334", "EAC2134250335", "EAC2134250336", "EAC2134250337", "EAC2134250338", "EAC2134250339", "EAC2134250340", "EAC2134250341", "EAC2134250342", "EAC2134250343", "EAC2134250344", "EAC2134250345", "EAC2134250346", "EAC2134250347", "EAC2134250348", "EAC2134250349", "EAC2134250350", "EAC2134250351", "EAC2134250352", "EAC2134250353", "EAC2134250354", "EAC2134250355", "EAC2134250356", "EAC2134250357", "EAC2134250358", "EAC2134250359", "EAC2134250360", "EAC2134250361", "EAC2134250362", "EAC2134250363", "EAC2134250364", "EAC2134250365", "EAC2134250366", "EAC2134250367", "EAC2134250368", "EAC2134250369", "EAC2134250370", "EAC2134250371", "EAC2134250372", "EAC2134250373", "EAC2134250374", "EAC2134250375", "EAC2134250376", "EAC2134250377", "EAC2134250378", "EAC2134250379", "EAC2134250380", "EAC2134250381", "EAC2134250382", "EAC2134250383", "EAC2134250384", "EAC2134250385", "EAC2134250386", "EAC2134250387", "EAC2134250388", "EAC2134250389", "EAC2134250390", "EAC2134250391", "EAC2134250392", "EAC2134250393", "EAC2134250394", "EAC2134250395", "EAC2134250396", "EAC2134250397", "EAC2134250398", "EAC2134250399", "EAC2134250400", "EAC2134250401", "EAC2134250402", "EAC2134250403", "EAC2134250404", "EAC2134250405", "EAC2134250406", "EAC2134250407", "EAC2134250408", "EAC2134250409", "EAC2134250410", "EAC2134250411", "EAC2134250412", "EAC2134250413", "EAC2134250414", "EAC2134250415", "EAC2134250416", "EAC2134250417", "EAC2134250418", "EAC2134250419"]
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        results = [executor.submit(getStatus, x) for x in casenumbers]
        
    print(results)
```

This is not working and i get nothing printed in the terminal. How to improve this code, Thanks.

Comment: You can't run two tasks on one selenium driver at the same time.

Comment: @KlausD. I changed the code by initializing a new driver every time, it works but slower than before and after like 10 times it gives me error '<Future at 0x7fadec9782d0 state=finished raised WebDriverException>'